# The similar function of "tf.Session().partial_run()" in Pytorch

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I am trying to use Pytorch to reimplement a project, but I have some troubles to find a similar function of "partial_run" of Tensorflow. Can you show me what it is?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the partial run function, as Pytorch objects hold actual values (and are not just abstracted computation/input nodes in a graph that only hold values once the computation graph is triggered - with `Session.(partial)run`).

So when you code something in pytorch, you can (mostly) just think of it as writing numpy code. There, too, the objects you create when writing your code will hold actual values that you can manipulate.

Besides being more "traditional" this has the great consequence that Pytorch thus allows you to debug code using a traditional python debugger.

Comment: Thanks! Your explanation helps me a lot.